# WooCommerce Google Analytics: Send order information on non-standard success page

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, woocommerce, orders

I have a WooCommerce website that is customized but runs analytics via the official woocommerce addon. I've been told that the analytics doesn't capture BACS orders when they've been set to "Complete" on the admin end.

I assume this is understandable considering there's no success page involved, so i thought the best way to go through this would be to build a function for functions.php that, if it was a BACS going from "on hold" to Complete", it would send the analytics data.

Unfortunately im struggling with the analytics part of this. I understand i can send objects to google analytics so it sees the object data but i'm wondering if it automatically figures out that it's a woocommerce order?

Has anyone had any experience with this? If so, am i thinking about how to capture this the wrong way? Should it be capturing it on complete regardless?

*Edit*: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce i've been looking here and i assume this is what i'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is not the case, you should need to get WooCommerce Google Analytics **"Pro"** (commercial) version of the plugin, that handle some features **that the "free" version don't handle** *(regarding BACS Completed orders)* like:

- Tracking impressions on Checkout completed, that doesn’t go to thank you page.
- Tracking impressions on Manually (admin) created order completed.

See: [WooCommerce Google Analytics Pro vs Free](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-google-analytics-pro-vs-free/)

Now if you are enough skilled, you could achieve this yourself, but it's quite broad, advanced and complicated…

Comment: This is exactly what i needed confirmation on. Thank you very much!